# Dismantling a WAVE file

Tags: audio, header, wave

sorry for this not being a programming question directly, but more indirectly as i try to batch convert audio files, which is proving difficult.

I have an audio file which i exported from a package. This audio file is of the RIFF WAVE format. As far as i have read up on headers, normal headers are 44 bytes long. Which contains the sub parts "fmt " and "data". However, this header shows all kind of weird junk, which i cannot actually place anywhere.
If anyone is an audio guru of sorts, please help me out on how to make this audio file accessible for most audio players? i do not care to lose some of the header data as long as it plays the actual content.

Here is a screenshot of my current header data unaltered:
[image: http://puu.sh/2JtWg.png]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this WAVE thing is just a container, and it actually contains a .ogg. I used ww2ogg 3rd party tool to get out these .ogg files as wave. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 2):

44Bytes is the size of a minimal Wav File header.  The format allows for other data chunks in the header in addition to the Riff, fmt and data chunks.

It looks like you have some cue information in your file.  This is not a problem, most audio players should accept a wav file with these chunks.

[How to write cues/markers to a WAV file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550819/how-to-write-cues-markers-to-a-wav-file-in-net) discusses how to add a cue chunk to a file.

http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html covers some of the additional chunks a wav file can have.

Mike

Comment: Dear Mike, This does give some extra info which i searched for myself as well. It seems that this wave file is marked as format: FF FF, being used only for ''experimental'' audio. Is there any way to analyze this audio data to try and get a normal playable file out of it anyway?

Comment: The AudioFormat is FF.  A value other than 1 implies compression (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).  You will need to research where you got the file from to find out what compression they have used.  The file seems very bizarre as it appears to also have FF channels of audio...

Comment: No, it has 2 channels of audio. I checked it out in hex workshop to compare to default WAVE files. and the format is marked FF FF, the channel count is 02 00. I am not sure ho the audio could have been created :/

Answer (score -1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV there is a table of wave files with different comperssion. You can just investigate in HEX editor a value of `AudioFormat` field of `fmt` chunk, to get a list of most common codecs used for compression.